# AngularJS: ng-repeat gives $rootscope.infdig error (inifite loop)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, infinite-loop, angularjs-digest

First of all.. sorry for long code, but I want to make something clear. (My question is situated at the bottom)

I'm trying to get all the contacts of 1 customer, first I tried to call the function `getContacts(customer.id)` inside the `ng-repeat directive` as you can see in the HTML code. But this resulted in an inifine loop (*$rootscope.infdig*).

So I moved the function to the `ng-init directive` but now I'm getting this error:

[image: Unexpected token <]

**index.html**

```
<tr ng-repeat="customer in customers">
    <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
    <td ng-init="contacts = getContacts(customer.id)">
        <div ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
            {{contact.firstname + " " + contact.lastname}}
        </div>
    </td
</tr>
```

**CustomerService.js**

This is a javascript file in which I'm getting some data from a Mysql database (via PHP-file)

```
angular.module("crmApp").factory("CustomerService", function ($http) {
    return {
        //get all customers
        getCustomers: function () {
            return $http.get("/php/customersGET").then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            })
        },

        //get all contacts of 1 customer
        getContactsByCustomersId: function (customers_id) {
            return $http.get("/php/contactsGET/?customers_id=" + customers_id).then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
});
```

**CustomerController.js**

I tried to console.log the return value of the `getContactsByCustomersId()` function but it shows something like: **d {$$state: Object}**

```
angular.module("crmApp").controller("CustomerController", function ($scope, $http, CustomerService) {

    //get all customers
    CustomerService.getCustomers().then(function (data) {
        $scope.customers = data;
    });

    //get all contacts by customers_id
    $scope.getContacts = function (customers_id) {
        return CustomerService.getContactsByCustomersId(customers_id).then(function (data) {
            return data;
        });
    };
});
```

**MY QUESTION**: 'How can I access the returned data of the `getContactsByCustomersId()` function and use it in my html code ???

Please, ask me if something is not clear enough !
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Since you need to display the contacts at the time of page loading its better to get these data beforehand.Asynchronously loading contacts will not fit into this scenario.

Comment: So I need to load ALL the contacts and then check which contacts belongs to which customer ?

Comment: @NickSpriet, yes. Load all customers and then get each customer on ng-repeat

Comment: Yes You can do that, Here is a minimal snippet achieving this (JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Amitesh_Bharat/5m8pxtru/)

Comment: Or you can return with each customer an array of contacts then you can iterate over it

Comment: I tried to load all the customers and all the contacts in 1 time... and then I filtered the contacts list by customers_id, but sometimes (when I refresh the page) I cannot see them... I think there is a delay and they're not loaded fast enough... Thank you for your time to comment on my question ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should add another php action which returns customers along with contacts using some kind of sql join.

Then you can use your nested ng-repeat like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="customer in customers">
    <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
    <td>
        <div ng-repeat="contact in customer.contacts">
            {{contact.firstname + " " + contact.lastname}}
        </div>
    </td
</tr>
```